# Is there a semantically complete system of direct-method natural deduction/sequent calculus?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, deduction

Does anybody know of a system of direct-method *natural deduction/sequent calculus*, in other words, a system that does not require (or even incorporate) conditional (and indirect) proof method(s) and that is (at least claimed to be) *semantically* complete (regardless of whether or not it has been established to be syntactically complete)?

I am thinking that the intuitionists might have come up with such systems given their constructivist inclinations, but I am not finding anything.

(I wrestled with whether to post this on the mathematics stack exchange or here.  I hope I made the right choice.)

Comment: Intuitionsitic logic is complete without Double Negation, which is equivalent to [Proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction#Principle) in the form : **from not P we have a contra, then conclude with P**. But [Intuistionistic logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) needs Conditional proof.

Comment: In the logic community, is it not (sensed to be) somewhat tendentious to claim that a logical system that requires conditional proof is _semantically_ complete given that there is no way to construct a formal proof for the validity of conditional proof (which makes sense as it is a method/technique, not a rule)?  A deduction theorem only justifies and defines the use of conditional proof for a given system.  It does not _prove_ anything.  Indeed, couldn't this be what Irving Copi was on to?  After all, he dropped the method(s) of (both) conditional proof (and indirect proof) from his system.